# How do I find the revisions made by a specific Subversion user?

Tags: svn

Using the command line, I'd like to see all changesets made by a particular user. Is this possible? I've looked at the documentation for `svn log` but can't see how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this using pure Subversion. But you can do it [with `sed`](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-08/0748.shtml):

```
svn log | sed -n '/username/,/-----$/ p'
```

This finds each instance of the username, and then prints everything up to the dashed line which marks the end of a record in the log.

The search pattern is very flexible - you can easily modify it to search for other things. For example,

```
svn log | sed -n '/Dec 2009/,/-----$/ p'
```

Would return all commits made in December (by any author).

**Edit:** If you don't want the actual commit message, but just the summary metadata, then you can just use `grep`, in an analogous way to William Leara's Windows [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976012/how-do-i-find-the-revisions-made-by-a-specific-subversion-user/2978127#2978127):

```
svn log | grep username
```

Comment: The whitespace between / and p is ignored by sed; some people might find the different formatting easier to read at a glance.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind reading log in XML format, here's how with [XML Starlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
svn log --xml --verbose <directory> | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/log/logentry/author[text()='<wanted author>']/.." -c "."
```

If you don't want those files to be listed, remove `--verbose`.

Here's example output without verbose.

```
$ svn log --xml zfce | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/log/logentry/author[text()='pekka.jarvinen']/.." -c "." 

<logentry revision="157">
<author>pekka.jarvinen</author>
<date>2009-09-26T19:23:40.060050Z</date>
<msg>fix</msg>
</logentry><logentry revision="156">
<author>pekka.jarvinen</author>
<date>2009-09-25T20:40:01.823746Z</date>
<msg>Dojo files are now downloaded from Google. Also some XHTML JS fixes (CDATA to &lt;script&gt;).</msg>
</logentry><logentry revision="155">
<author>pekka.jarvinen</author>
<date>2009-09-25T17:28:14.501392Z</date>
<msg>Added spans</msg>
</logentry><logentry revision="154">
<author>pekka.jarvinen</author>
<date>2009-09-25T17:21:17.375304Z</date>
<msg>Changed behavior: default.css is now not used as base. CSS in .INI configuration is always loaded.</msg>
</logentry><logentry revision="151">
<author>pekka.jarvinen</author>
<date>2009-04-10T00:24:41.683379Z</date>
<msg>Added more PHP and Apache information</msg>
</logentry>

...
```

Comment: By far the most powerful IMHO, but I'm not able to make xmlstarlet work in streaming mode, so I have to cut-and-close the log's tags.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest approach is to use Subversion 1.8+ command-line client; it supports `--search` and `--search-and` options that allow you to filter `svn log` output to display only revisions that match the search pattern you specify.

[SVNBook 1.8 | `svn log` command-line reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html),

[Subversion 1.8 Release Notes | `svn log` can filter log messages based on search terms.](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search)

For example,

search for revisions committed by user Sally or Harry:

```
$ svn log --search Sally --search Harry https://svn.example.com/repos/test
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1701 | Sally | 2011-10-12 22:35:30 -0600 (Wed, 12 Oct 2011) | 1 line

Add a reminder.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1564 | Harry | 2011-10-09 22:35:30 -0600 (Sun, 09 Oct 2011) | 1 line

Merge r1560 to the 1.0.x branch.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
$
```

search for revisions committed by user Sally to /foo/bar/helloworld.cpp:

```
$ svn log --verbose --search Sally --search-and /foo/bar/helloworld.cpp https://svn.example.com/repos/test
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1555 | Sally | 2011-07-15 22:33:14 -0600 (Fri, 15 Jul 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
M /foo/bar/helloworld.cpp

Typofix.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1530 | Sally | 2011-07-13 07:24:11 -0600 (Wed, 13 Jul 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
M /foo/bar/helloworld.cpp
M /foo/build

Fix up some svn:ignore properties.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
$
```

**NOTE:** You can also use [TortoiseSVN's Revision Log Dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) to perform searches and filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Windows version:

```
svn log | find "William_Leara"
```

The output looks like:

```
r11506 | William_Leara | 2009-12-23 19:29:12 -0600 (Wed, 23 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11505 | William_Leara | 2009-12-23 15:18:37 -0600 (Wed, 23 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11504 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 19:16:12 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11503 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 19:04:15 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11502 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 18:49:33 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11501 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 18:26:45 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11500 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 18:05:04 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11499 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 17:25:25 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11498 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 17:03:18 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11497 | William_Leara | 2009-12-22 16:54:59 -0600 (Tue, 22 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11494 | William_Leara | 2009-12-21 14:36:20 -0600 (Mon, 21 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
r11491 | William_Leara | 2009-12-19 12:48:49 -0600 (Sat, 19 Dec 2009) | 12 lines
```

etc.

Comment: This is equivalent to `svn log | grep 'William_Leara'` in Unix. I hadn't considered that the OP might just want the meta-data. The `sed` solution in my answer extracts the commit messages as well, which may or may not be what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, using [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) version of `sed`, I needed to use these regexps instead, matching to ---- at the next start of line:

```
svn log | sed -n "/username/,/^----/p"
```