# How to get all commit messages within a given timeframe of a user with SVN

Tags: svn

Is it possible to get all commit messages of a user within a given timeframe?
In the past I used the Trac to browse the SVN, but this service is not available anymore.

The best would be to do it with Linux on commandline.

Best Regards,
Christian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svn log -r {date1}:{date2} --xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/log/logentry/author[text()='author_name']/.." -t -v "/log/logentry/msg"
```

See Subversion Book ([one](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html), [two](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html)), [xmlstarlet documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) and [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976012/how-do-i-find-the-revisions-made-by-a-specific-subversion-user).

Comment: +1: Didn't know about the xmlstarlet command. It's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Subversion 1.8 [you can use `--search` command-line option with `svn log` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

This command-line option allows you to search your repository history for:

- revision's author (svn:author unversioned property),
- date (svn:date unversioned property),
- log message text (svn:log unversioned property),
- and paths affected by the particular revision (use `svn log --verbose`).